# SWT Label negrita

Tags: java, swt

Es una aplicación RCP, se tiene un(a) LIST de Nombres, esta se descarga por medio de un Bucle FOR.

Es decir son Items de menú y que se ubican a la izquierda de la pantalla con su respectiva capa(composite).

Ahora, esto funciona, la dificultad/lo que se necesita aqui es que cuando uno haga doble click sobre un Item este reciba caracteristica de "SWT.BOLD" y cuando se haga click a otro Item, el anterior reciba SWT.NONE y el escogido SWT.BOLD....

Aqui el codigo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            final Label l1 = neueLabel(shell, "label "+i, i);
            l1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
                    if(e.button==1)
                        l1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 9, SWT.BOLD));
                }
            });
        }
```

De antemano gracias por una respuesta.
Ben

Comment: Guarda una referencia del botón anterior, `previousFocused` y del actual, `currentFocused`. Cambia sus valores al hacer clic en otro *item*, p.ej.: `previousFocused = currentFocused; currentFocused = this;`

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Paul. El problema aqui es que, el componente es un Label y no se como cambiar de referencia del anterior al actual...serial genial ejemplo en codigo, Gracias.